# Can I make a page appear as a blog post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I created this page on my site: http://christmaspast.media/christmas-podcast-guide/ Each of the items on the page is a post that I created with a custom post type.

My question is whether I can treat this entire page as a blog post, and have it appear on my blog homepage along with all the other posts in my blog feed.

If not, is there a way to accomplish the same thing with a post? (AFAIK, it's not possible to embed multiple custom  posts into another post, which is why I created a page instead.)

Comment: "AFAIK, it's not possible to embed multiple custom posts into another post, which is why I created a page instead." Not true. You could, for example, create a shortcode that outputs your CPTs and insert that shortcode in any post.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that!!! If true, it solves my problem. Can you point me to the documentation for that? Would it be one shortcode per CPT? Or a single shortcode that outputs all specified CPTs?

Comment: A shortcode can output anything you want. Here's the documentation: [Shortcode API | WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a filter `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query. [Check Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).
Replace custom_post_type string with yours.

```
function pref_add_custom_post_type_to_loop( $query ) {
    // don't run in admin area
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        // add custom post types
        if ( $query->is_feed() || ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_front_page()) ) {
            $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'custom_post_type'));
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pref_add_custom_post_type_to_loop');
```